# Making only a part of QTableWidgetItem have background

Tags: c++, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Is it possible in Qt to make a QTableWidget cell have background in only a part of th cell? I mean, I want to have cell with eg. 60% of the cell being red and 40% being white, so something like the data bars in MS Excel. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I couldn't find it before. Thanks.

Comment: I was lucky with google. I had to fight my urge just to post an answer. But I'm glad I could help you this way. Your question title is actually the better one.